# I need to improve a function that selects all text in a table

Tags: javascript

I have this function which selects all text in an element (table in this case)

```
function SelectText(element) {

    var text = document.getElementById(element);
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);

        range.select(); 
}
```

I need help making it do the following

1. Ignore some words that I specify (ie. not select them)
2. Automatically put the selected text in clipboard

Comment: I have not seen any functionality that allows you to make multiple text selections...

Answer (score 2):

That code is IE only, and IE doesn't support multiple selections. The only major browser that does is Firefox, so you may want to abandon that idea. Also, it's not generally possible to copy content to the clipboard with JavaScript, although there are Flash-based hacks like Zeroclipboard (http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard) that do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
range.execCommand("Copy");
```

That will put your text in the clipboard.

I don't think ignoring words is possible. You could potentially remove the text before copying.